Missing AWS credential on EC2 in node only
I'm setting up a ec2 box. I've set the AWS credentials via a AIM Role. This is working for the AWS CLI.
bash-5.2$ aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************4QOO         iam-role    
secret_key     ****************qSk2         iam-role    
    region                us-west-2             imds    

I can list s3 buckets with the CLI just fine:
bash-5.2$ aws s3 ls
2020-06-25 20:18:09 <BUCKET NAME 1>
2020-06-25 22:27:28 <BUCKET NAME 2>

When I try to do the same thing from node it fails:
bash-5.2$ cat test.js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
S3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err);
});

bash-5.2$ node test.js
null
SyntaxError [CredentialsError]: Missing credentials in config
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /PATH/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/metadata_service.js:115:38
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/PATH/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/metadata_service.js:74:45)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  time: 2024-04-24T20:14:11.591Z,
  originalError: {
    message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
    code: 'CredentialsError',
    time: 2024-04-24T20:14:11.591Z,
    originalError: { message: 'Unexpected end of JSON input' }
  }
}

Why isn't node picking up the credentials?
